# How to call a custom Vue 3 method from outside vue app in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a simple app written in Vue. What I want is just to call a method from Vue, a custom method, outside of the Vue.createApp() method.

My code:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
data() {
    return {
        data: ["this","is","an", "example"],
    }
 },
 methods: {
  getData() {
    return this.data;
  },
 },
});


app.mount('#app');

// This instruction fails!
console.log(app.getData());
```

When I am trying to execute the method on the last line, i get in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
```

Why I can not execute the method? what is wrong?

Comment: why are you doing that?

Comment: I need to do a more complex calculations based on the Data of the app, but the very first step, that is executing the method, does not work

Comment: i think what you're deciding to do is a bad practice, you could define a component and use the multiple options to do your logic and show the result

Comment: Brahim is right. It might be worth exploring Vuex, Mixins or Composition functions to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've posted does in fact **[work](https://jsfiddle.net/an7tvk23/)**.

```js
/* only the style has been changed */

const { createApp } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
    template: '<div />',

    data: () => ({
        data: ['this', 'is', 'an', 'example'],
    }),

    methods: {
        getData() {
            return this.data;
        },
    },
}).mount('#app');

console.log(app.getData());
```

**Edit**

This is an [anti-pattern](https://wiki.c2.com/?AntiPattern) and should generally be avoided. If you're looking to share state between distant components you should take a look at [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org). If the components are close together, i.e. *parent* and *child*, look into [props](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#props).

Could you provide more information on the motivation behind this?

Comment: this is weird, i've just tried out in the snippet code runner here in SO and it doesn't work, but in your example it works

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim interesting, I wonder if it's because the component isn't ready before we call `console.log`... in any case, this is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 6):

For the specific question:

> Why I can not execute the method?

The reason is because you're calling the method on the application instance, not the component where the function is defined. The first parameter to `createApp` is the root component.

To get hold of the root component, use:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({ /* root component's data, methods, etc */ });
const root = app.mount("#app");

// component methods accessible on return value from mount()
console.log(root.getData());
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question asked. The variable needs to be the one returned by .mount() not the one returned by the .createApp(). I wasted hours on this until I saw your answer.