# Vue 3, how I can fire some method in App.vue with params from outside JS? or set some prop?

Tags: jquery, vuejs3

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div ref="containerForMessage"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {isProxy, toRaw, ref} from 'vue';

    export default {
        name: 'App',
        data() {
            return {
                someProp: {},
            };
        },
        computed:{},
        methods : {
            setMessage: function(message = ''){
              this.$refs.containerForMessage = message;
            },

        }
    }
</script>
```

I want insert text message in containerForMessage when I click button, smt like that:

example of JQuery:

```
<button id='fireButton'>This message will insert</button>

$( "#fireButton" ).on( "click", function() {
  let textInsert = $(this).text();
///...how I can use setMessage in Vue component in this event? Is it posible?
} );
```

If that isn't posible, can I set some prop in component from outside JS?

Like this

```
<button id='fireButton'>This button set someProp in Vue3 component</button>

$( "#fireButton" ).on( "click", function() {
  let textInsert = {"1":"one","2":"two"};
  ///set someProp in Vue 3 = textInsert ; )) 
} );
```

I have page with app and native JS (or JQuery) and need little communicate between it, how is it posible? )

Thanks for the help

Edit:

I found some solution...but it dont look good :|

```
App.vue
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div ref="containerForMessage"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import $ from 'jquery';
    import {JQuery} from 'jquery';
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    export default {
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        components: {

        },
        mounted() {
            $("body").on("custom-event", this.setMessage);
        },
        beforeUnmount() {
            $("body").off("custom-event", this.setMessage);
        },
        methods: {
            setMessage: function(obj = {}){
                if(obj.message){
                    this.$refs.containerForMessage = obj.message;
                }
            },
        },
        computed: {},
    }
</script>
```

And outside do smth like:

```
var event = jQuery.Event("custom-event");
event.message = "This message will insert";
$('body').trigger(event);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a custom Vue 3 method from outside vue app in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758293/how-to-call-a-custom-vue-3-method-from-outside-vue-app-in-javascript)

Comment: I try it, but in vue 3 it doesn't work well

Answer (score -2):

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div ref="containerForMessage"></div>
  </div>

  <button @click="setMessage()">set message</button>

</template>


<script setup>
import {ref} from "vue";

const containerForMessage = ref(null)

function setMessage (message = 'your message') {
  containerForMessage.value.innerHTML = message 
// you can use innerHTML or innerText
  
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't solve question. How do it on clear Vue3 I know. But I need solution with outside JS event :(

Comment: Hi, can you explain how this can address the question? There are no comments...  Be sure to read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you